Не работает чтение текстового файла в C++
В цикле While получаю ввод из текстового файла с проверкой на EOF, в итоге последний символ в файле зацикливается и выводится бесконечно, какая-то проблема с EOF, при том что этот файл я создаю ранее в коде ниже. Подскажите почему так и как это исправить?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>

const int f_size = 50;


int main(void)
{
    int u_age;
    char ch;
    std::string u_name, u_city, f_name;

    std::ofstream u_txt1;

    std::cout << "Enter your name: ";
    std::cin >> u_name;
    std::cout << "Enter your age: ";
    std::cin >> u_age;
    std::cout << "Enter your city: ";
    std::cin >> u_city;
    f_name = u_name + "_info.txt";
    u_txt1.open(f_name);
    u_txt1 << "Your name is " << u_name << std::endl;
    u_txt1 << "Your age is " << u_age << std::endl;
    u_txt1 << "Your city is " << u_city;
    u_txt1.close();

    std::ifstream u_txt2;
    u_txt2.open(f_name);
    if (!u_txt2.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "Couldnot open this file: " << f_name << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Programm terminating";
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    u_txt2.get(ch);
    while (!(ch == EOF))
    {
        std::cout << ch;
        u_txt2.get(ch);
    }
    u_txt2.close();


    return 0;
};  


Начнем с того интересного факта, что ch у вас — char, а EOF — int, и именно для того, чтобы его значение не совпадало ни с одним значением char!

Метод std::ifstream(char_type & ch) пытается получить один символ, и сохраняет его, если его удалось прочитать из файла.
В противном случае, метод оставляет ch без изменения и устанавливает failbit и eofbit биты.
Когда std::ifstream доходит до конца файла, то EOF не сохраняется в ch. ch остаётся прежним, поэтому цикл while (!(ch == EOF)) продолжается бесконечно.
Поменяйте его на:
while (u_txt2.get(ch).good())
{
    std::cout << ch;
}

Метод good() возвращает true, если самая последняя операция ввода/вывода была завершена успешно. Соответственно, когда std::ifstream обнаруживет конец файла, этот метод возращает false, и цикл прерывается.

я сделал так как вы сказали, в результате выдает неправильный, больше половины символов пропущены, вывод выглядит вот так:
Enter your name: Bill
Enter your age: 24
Enter your city: Boston
ornm sBl
oraei 4Yu iyi otn

Вероятно, вы 1. не убрали ненужное u_txt2.get(ch); перед циклом, и 2. не убрали совершенно ненужное u_txt2.get(ch); в цикле... Результат - вы теряете половину считанного из файла :)

@AMIACK, обратите внимание, что Вам ответил Harry коментарием выше. Вам нужно убрать все u_txt2.get(ch); кроме той, что находится в условии while в скобках, тогда Ваша программа заработает как надо.

Может проще использовать построчное чтение?
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::fstream txtfile;
    txtfile.open("exp.txt");
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(txtfile, line))
    {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    txtfile.close();

    return 0;
}

